# Google pubsub - message queue cleanup

Tags: google-api, message-queue

What happens to messages in a pubsub queue that don't get acknowledged? Does the system eventually clean them up ala kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unacknowledged messages in a subscription are deleted after 7 days according to https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas